# How to set C++ language standard for VS2019 in an Unreal project?

Tags: c++, unreal-4, visual-studio, filesystem

I am trying to a simple thing, just like that, in a header file;

```
#include <filesystem>
#include <iostream>
 
namespace fs = std::filesystem;
```

And IntelliSense goes:
`namespace std has no member filesystem`.

Okay no worries, it's an easy [fix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50668814/vs2017-e0135-namespace-std-has-no-member-filesystem).
Just set the C++ language standard in the propery pages...

Well, it turns out it isn't, it's not an option in Unreal VS project. Tried typing in search bar, View -> Property pages, but no luck.

Okay let's try doing the whole [thing](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Walk_a_directory/Recursively#C.2B.2B) in a console project first.

Same message from IntelliSense as before.

Ok, no worries, I found [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/working-with-project-properties?view=vs-2019).

I found my settings under: Project > projectname Properties

And voila, the console app works.

Let's try it in the Unreal project.

Well, well... My options are limited here.

[image: myueoptions]

I had a look around in the project settings as well:

[image: projectsettings]

How do I get this filesystem header work with my project?

Comment: Googling "ue4 c++17" gives me several different results with varying degrees of success from users, none of which seem to suggest changing this from VS or UE4 settings.

Comment: What is it that you're trying to achieve in the end?  It may be that there's no way to do this as you're trying to do it but Unreal may have a solution of its own that will work.

Comment: I am trying to load fbx files, and load the file structure tree into a string. Something like that:


https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Walk_a_directory/Recursively#C.2B.2B


     Not sure if this is the "Unreal" way of handling files.

Comment: But for now, I would like to load/read files

Comment: Downvoters please comment

Comment: My guess is that the downvotes are because your question doesn't show any attempt to implement the approaches Tyyppi_77 mentioned can be [found with a search](https://www.google.com/search?q=use+c%2B%2B17+in+unreal). Can you show us what happens when you try implementing these approaches?

Comment: Unreal uses FFileManager.  I've never used it so can't answer your question but it looks like it has similar functions to those in your link.

Comment: Don't fret about votes - it's just a number. What matters is making progress. You now have several leads proposed here in the comments. Follow-up on those leads, and if they solve your problem, post your solution as an Answer. If they don't solve your problem, edit your question to show what you tried and where it went wrong. Typically folks will reverse their downvotes once a question is improved to show research effort, or new voters will upvote the higher-quality question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, found the solution [here](https://forums.unrealengine.com/development-discussion/c-gameplay-programming/1603585-what-s-needed-for-using-c-17).

```
CppStandard = CppStandardVersion.Cpp17;
```

I added this to my myproject.Build.cs

Comment: Make sure to close VS and in UE4 do File -> Refresh Visual Studio project Files after this change. This fixes the project settings for IntelliSense to work.